# Decrease varchar length for acl class in Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, acl, sonata-admin

I have a symfony project (2.8 version) that run the following bundles :

- Sonata Admin Bundle
- Sonata User Bundle
- FOS User Bundle

This website is linked with a mySQL database (version 5.6).

I had issues with doctrine when I want to update my database scheme with the following command :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Because the varchar(255)type was not supported by innoDB engine and my database so I decreased all varchar to 191 length and now it's working.

My issue now is that doctrine want to generate tables (linked with acl apparently) that I cannot control like the following :

```
CREATE TABLE acl_classes (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, class_type VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_69DD750638A36066 (class_type), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

How can I decrease the length of class_type to apply varchar(191) ?

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix is in /vendor/symfony/security-acl/Dbal/Schema.php line 70 https://github.com/symfony/security-acl/blob/master/Dbal/Schema.php#L70

```
$table->addColumn('class_type', 'string', array('length' => 200));
```

change to

```
$table->addColumn('class_type', 'string', array('length' => 190));
```

Or you can try `utf8mb4` encoding:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, I have already these default table options but in that case the issues are due to the 5.6 version of MySql... Thanks a lot for the file to fix it works perfectly now !